# Trouble adding ".sh" file to environment .

Tags: ubuntu

I have an application that requires me to start it from within the "bin" folder to get it running as follows :

```
./pio commad
```

I want to be able to run it without entering the folder and running the file "manually" (so as to say) . How may I modify my system such that the file may be used as following :

```
pio command
```

How would I go about doing this ?

I am a newbie to Linux so please provide me with an answer appropriate to my skill level . Give me principles, give me links, give me clarity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a variable called PATH in every sh/bash session.
example:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Every one of those directories, declared with syntax directory1:directory2:directory3, is a place where bash looks for executable when you type a command.

If you type `mousepad file.txt` it will find an executable called "mousepad" in the folder `/usr/bin`.

If you want your program to be called the same way as `mousepad` you must either:

- Place it in one of the directories contained in `$PATH`
- Place a link (symbolic or not) to your program in one of those directories
  `$ sudo ln -s "/home/username/mydir/myprogram" /usr/local/bin/"
- Add the directory in the `$PATH` variable like 
  `$PATH=$PATH:/home/username/mydir`

As an alternative, you can alias the command with

```
$ alias commandIWantToRun="/home/...../...../myprogram"
```

an then run it with `commandIWantToRun`

If you chose not to move your program, beware that with a new terminal session the changes to the `$PATH` and the `alias` will disappear.
In that case, you might want to create, if it doesn't already exists, a file called `/home/username/.bash_aliases` and put inside the commands you want to be automatically run at the beguinning of every session. For more information search `.bash_aliases` on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you . Much appreciated .

Comment: I must add that the `alias` solution addes the possibility of including the arguments you wish to be default. `alias ll="ls -l -1 -a"` will call the program `ls` with the arguments just as specified in the alias. It is indeed called `alias` :)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this is either creating an alias or linking it to /usr/bin

CREATING ALIAS
I will be creating a .sh file in /etc/profile.d as root

```
sudo nano /etc/profile.d/test.sh
```

And type in

```
alias pio='/bin/path/to/pio'
```

Save and restart any terminal

OR

LINKING 
Type

```
sudo ln -s /bin/path/to/pio /usr/bin/pio
```

Then run

```
pio
```